# Pop-in banner for "This answer has been locked or deleted"

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, popups

According to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73200/answer-question-hit-submit-and-seeing-sorry-this-question-has-been-deleted), a banner pops in when a *question* has been locked or deleted. I'm wondering if we can do the same for answers.

Currently we see the pop-in banner if a user has made a change to their answer. But several times now I've written up long, drawn-out comment to an answer, and in the meantime the user has realized their error and deleted their own answer. Currently I don't know that anything has changed until I hit the "add comment" button. Why isn't there a pop-up to notify me of the delete when it happens, just like the way it works for edits?

Comment: How much time are you spending writing out these monster comments?

Comment: @random sometimes a couple of minutes, depending on whether I need to fetch links or other resources in order to demonstrate my point. In the grand scheme it's not huge, but I don't think adding the banner would hurt anything, either. And would be useful in the general case, too, if I'm sitting on the page - even if I'm not currently typing a comment.

Comment: I've had a "this post has been edited" banner pop up on a message, and upon clicking the update thingy the answer was blanked; apparently it had been deleted. Not sure if it was intended. It didn't say "this post has been deleted" so I think it might have been edited, then deleted

Comment: Because Stack Overflow wasn't written in WPF?

There's a limit to how much plumbing you can put in a web page, and we're not really here for the comments anyway; we're here for the questions and answers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey again, I'm not talking *just* about the case where I'm entering a comment. I can also be writing an answer and if I'm referencing someone else's answer it can be useful to know that that answer has been deleted instead of not finding out until I refresh the page. I also disagree that this would be a lot of plumbing to add the banner as a trigger to delete in addition to edit operations.

Comment: This already works for question closures.  It doesn't work for deletions?

Comment: It doesn't work for *answer* deletions, no. I don't know about the behavior for questions, I don't think I would have ever known if a question was deleted while I was on the page, so I'm not sure.